# Unable to install package (connection problems)

Tags: packages

I am having problems installing the package thesis from the MikTex Package Manager. Every time I try to install it I get the following message.

"*The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state. The MiKTeX project page (https://miktex.org) might have more info.*"

I have checked miktex.org but no report have been made in regard to the MikTex Package Manager being down.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try another repository.

Comment: miktex.org says clearly that there is a problem and that it is offline. https://miktex.org/alert/update-problem-6463

Comment: Sorry. I guess it was me who couldn't find the message. -

Comment: you can wait that server be on-line again that the problems with last update will be resolved (as noticed in the top of `miktex` web page)